# run a Perl script from Python and stop it when finishes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I call and run a perl script inside a python script. It calls properly the perl script, works, but it does not stop...it seems that the perl script doesn't stop.

How can i solve it? if I run manually the perl script alone it stops.

I use...

```
import subprocess

pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "/home/scripts/cat.pl"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your python program

```
pipe.wait()
```